# Jenkins Pipeline ${params.Environment} bad substitution

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to send commands to a *docker* container within *docker* run via a *Jenkins* pipeline.

The *Jenkins* machine is at a different server and the *docker* image is in a different server.

When I hard code the environment param, the scripts execute as expected. But whenever I try to replace it with the params, it errors out saying :

`bash: ${params.Environment} bad substitution`

This is my pipeline script

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
       parameters {
          choice(
              name: 'Environment',
              choices: ['qa','dev'],
              description: 'Passing the Environment'
            )
       }
       stages {
          stage('Environment') {
             steps {
                 echo " The environment is ${params.Environment}"
             }
          }
          stage('run') {
             steps {
                sh 'ssh 10.x.x.x \'sudo docker run --name docker_container_name docker_image_name sh -c "cd mytests ; pip3 install -r requirements.txt ; python3 runTests.py -env  ${params.Environment} "\''
             }
         }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sh` command's parameters needs to have double quotes, or triple double quotes.

```groovy
sh """ssh 10.x.x.x 'sudo docker run --name docker_container_name docker_image_name sh -c "cd mytests ; pip3 install -r requirements.txt ; python3 runTests.py -env  ${params.Environment} "'"""
```

In the Groovy language used by pipeline scripts, [single-quoted strings](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_single_quoted_string) don't do any interpolation at all, so the `${params.Environment}` string gets passed on as-is to the shell.  [Double-quoted strings](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_double_quoted_string) do perform interpolation, so the Groovy engine substitutes `${params.Environment}` before invoking the shell.

(You might look at the native support for [Using Docker with Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) which can avoid the `ssh 'sudo "..."'` wrapping, though it requires Jenkins be able to run Docker itself on the worker nodes.)